# Decoding unicode strings with base 10 integers escape sequences

Tags: python, unicode

As input I get strings like this

```
Funda\195\131\194\167\195\131\194\163o
```

which I get from the Cymru Whois service:

```sh
$ dig +short AS10417.asn.cymru.com TXT
"10417 | BR | lacnic | 2000-02-15 | Funda\195\131\194\167\195\131\194\163o de Desenvolvimento da Pesquisa, BR"
```

Correctly decoded that would result in:

```
Fundação
```

In hexadigital notation this is:

```
b'\xc3\xa7\xc3\xa3'
```

where 0xc3 is 195, 0xa7 is 167 and 0xa3 is 163, matching the numbers of the first and last character of each quadruple.

So,`\195\131\194\167` is `ç` and `\195\131\194\163`. It looks like Python cannot decode that, at least with the default parameters.

Is this kind of encoding common and is there any built-in functionality in Python to decode this *generically* (not specific to this string of course)?

Comment: What produces the input? It would be better, if possible, to change the producer to provide something standard (like a proper UTF-8-encoded text, or JSON), rather than this "proprietary" octal encoding.

Comment: "Is this kind of encoding common?" It is mojibake, which unfortunately is quite common.

Comment: "What produces the input?" I added the data source to the question. As it is a public service I cannot change it unfortunately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick here is to use a custom replacement routine in [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub):

> If `repl` is a function, it is called for every non-overlapping occurrence of `pattern`. The function takes a single match object argument, and returns the replacement string.

To convert the string to printable characters, *encode* it to `bytes` using `latin1`, which preserves all literal byte codes, then *decode* it as UTF-8:

```py
import re

text = r'Funda\195\131\194\167\195\131\194\163o'

print (bytes('Fundação','utf8')) # This is our target
print (bytes(re.sub (r'\\(\d+)', lambda x: chr(int(x.group(1))), text).encode('latin1')).decode('utf-8'))
```

However, your text is not simply UTF-8 encoded but *double* encoded!

```
b'Funda\xc3\xa7\xc3\xa3o'
FundaÃ§Ã£o
```

so decoding it into UTF-8 yields another UTF-8 encoded string. We need to translate *twice*:

```py
# This first line prints the byte values so you can compare it to the UTF-8 target:
print (bytes(re.sub (r'\\(\d+)', lambda x: chr(int(x.group(1))), text).encode('latin1')).decode('utf-8').encode('latin1'))

print (bytes(re.sub (r'\\(\d+)', lambda x: chr(int(x.group(1))), text).encode('latin1')).decode('utf-8').encode('latin1').decode('utf8'))
```

to finally get the output:

```
b'Funda\xc3\xa7\xc3\xa3o'
Fundação
```

Comment: Wow. This is unfortunate indeed. Not your answer of course, but that this exists at all.